# Why is my random number generator becoming an unused assignment when using it to input values for 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, random, netbeans

I have been making a basic game of battleship and to get the CPU to choose ship locations on a 2d array I am making two random number generators to pick values from 1 to 8 on a separate method. For some reason, the random generators show up as unused and I don't know why. so far this is what I have. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know.

```java
//calls method
board3 = CPUship(board3);
//displays result of method
for (int i = 0; i < board3.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board3.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(board3[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

```java
public static String[][] CPUship(String[][] board3) {
    int rowGenerate;
    int colGenerate;
    boolean valid2 = false;
    for (int CPUships = 0; CPUships < 6; CPUships++) {
        while (!valid2) {
            rowGenerate = (int) (9 * Math.random() + 0);
            colGenerate = (int) (9 * Math.random() + 0);
            if (!board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate].equalsIgnoreCase("#")) {
                board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate] = "#";
                valid2 = true;
            }
        }
        valid2 = false;
    }
    return board3;
}
```

Comment: I've copied your code, my IDE(Eclipse) tells me that everything except for "valid2" is used. What exactly is unused, ... what do you mean by "the random generators".

Comment: I am using the lines with "rowGenerated" and "colGenerated" as the random generators in the while statement but under (int) ( 9* Math.random() + 0) it am being shown as an unused variable

Comment: what IDE are you using (Eclipse, IntelliJ,...)?

Comment: while (valid2=false){ can not worke ... just use while(!valid2) ... to compare values use <=   >=  ==   !=  ... or ".equals(xy)"

Comment: I am using netbeans

Comment: if you change while (valid2=false) to while (!valid2) ... does Netbeans still complain?

Comment: so I changed the code fixing the valid2 and now it works but only displays 3 "#" instead of the 5 I need.

Comment: Can you edit your question so it shows how you call the CPUship method and also how you set the value of the board3 parameter?

Btw. I think you should remove the CPUships++; at the end of the for loop ... you don't need to increment the loop variable at the end ... it is already done by the CPUships++ in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should be a complete code

```
public static String[][] CPUship(String[][]board3){
    int rowGenerate;
    int colGenerate;
    
    for (int CPUships = 0; CPUships < 6; CPUships++) {
        boolean valid2=false;
        while (!valid2){ //instead of valid = false "
            rowGenerate = (int) ( 9* Math.random() + 0);
            colGenerate = (int) ( 9* Math.random() + 0);
            if (!board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate].equalsIgnoreCase ("#")){
                board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate]="#";
                valid2=true;
            }
            //removed the valid2=false, it does not "reset" automatically
            //removed the CPUships++ ... already done by the for loop 
        }
    }
    return board3;
}
```

or use break instead of the valid boolean

```
public static String[][] CPUship(String[][]board3){
    int rowGenerate;
    int colGenerate;
    
    for (int CPUships = 0; CPUships < 6; CPUships++) {
        while (true){ //instead of valid = false "
            rowGenerate = (int) ( 9* Math.random() + 0);
            colGenerate = (int) ( 9* Math.random() + 0);
            if (!board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate].equalsIgnoreCase ("#")){
                board3[rowGenerate][colGenerate]="#";
                break;
            }
            //removed the valid2=false, it does not "reset" automatically
            //removed the CPUships++ ... already done by the for loop 
        }
    }
    return board3;
}
```

Comment: this works but because the valid2 boolean becomes true after one valid entry it won't loop more than once also it shows a "missing javadoc" error for the last line

Comment: @Vardig25 I've moved the valid2 into the for loop and added a second solution.

Comment: Thank you for all the help I think I got it to work!